# Dark mode Icon not changed and not saved in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a dark mode button with my own dark theme. The theme is saved by Local Storage. Also when I click the button, then it's icon not change (moon to sun). But if I reload the page, the site is still in dark mode but the button icon's not changed. So heres a link which show you the problem if youo don't understant what i am talking about. [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/orabipro/pen/PozBzQO) Also heres my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

$('body').toggleClass(localStorage.toggled);

$(".darkmode-btn").on("click", function(){

  if (localStorage.toggled != 'dark') {

    $('body').toggleClass('dark', true);
    localStorage.toggled = "dark";

    
     
  } else {

    $('body').toggleClass('dark', false);
    localStorage.toggled = "";
    $(this).toggleClass("sun")


  }


});
});
```

```css
.dark{background-color: #222;}

.darkmode-btn {
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #08f;
}

.darkmode-btn:before,.darkmode-btn.moon:before,.darkmode-btn.sun:before {
  font-family: "fontawesome";

}
.darkmode-btn:before {
  content: '\f186';
}
.darkmode-btn.moon:before {
    content: '\f186';
}
.darkmode-btn.sun:before {
    content: '\f185';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="darkmode-btn">
</div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Try replacing `<div class="darkmode-btn"></div>` with a `button` tag

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".darkmode-btn").on("click", function(){
  if (localStorage.toggled != 'dark') {
    $('body').toggleClass('dark', true);
    localStorage.toggled = "dark";
    $(this).addClass("moon").removeClass("sun")
  } else {
    $('body').toggleClass('dark', false);
    localStorage.toggled = "";
    //$(this).toggleClass("sun").removeClass("sun")
    $(this).addClass("sun").removeClass("moon")
  }
});
});
```

This should help you.

Comment: When I click the button, then it's icon change (moon to sun). But if I reload the page, the site is still in dark mode but the button icon's is the moon again